# In CSS how do I create a class to put padding underneath an underlined heading?

Tags: css, wordpress, typography

I have a context specific class that I want to certain headings on the site and I'm using the following code to apply a 2px full width line under a heading:-

```css
.headingCustom2 {
  
  color:black; 
  text-align: center; 
  padding-top: 50px; 
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000; 
  padding-bottom: 3px;

}
```

I want to add 20px padding *beneath* the underline so there's space between it and the div below. It needs to be independent of padding:bottom. My searching has only returned results on padding-bottom which alters the distance between the heading and the underline. Wanted to keep it to a distinct class as there's a lot of headings across the site it will need to be applied to. The heading font, Heading 5 is also used in other non-underlined contexts. Anyway, I hope this question isn't too tiresome.

Comment: You're talking about `margin` property.

Comment: That's brilliant. All done. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use ::after

```
.headingCustom2::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
}
```